# Как включить список сразу несколько строк в определенное место списка?

Tags: python, массивы, list

Есть два списка:

```
list1= [
f'some text',
f'text2',
f'end of list',
]
list2 = [
'some text in list 2',
'other text'
]
```

Я хочу сформировать общий список:

```
list1= [
f'some text',
'some text in list 2',
'other text',
f'text2',
f'end of list',
]
```

но

```
list1.insert(1, list2)
```

выдает:

```
list1= [
f'some text',
[
'some text in list 2',
'other text'
],
f'text2',
f'end of list',
]
```

Как можно получить общий список из пяти строк одной командой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

совсем по-простому

```
list1[:1] + list2 + list1[1:]
```

или так

```
list1[1:1] = list2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1= [f'some text', f'text2', f'end of list',]
list2 = ['some text in list 2', 'other text']
list3 = list1 + list2
print(list3)
```

Comment: Это включит list2 в конец list3